# Is Suurballe's algorithm optimal?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Suppose an undirected (non-negative) weighted graph $G$. Given two of its nodes, we are asked to find the shortest simple cycle that contains at least those two. To clarify, the cycle can't repeat edges but *can* repeat nodes.

I recently found out [Suurballe's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm) which is said to compute such shortest cycle. Briefly, this algorithm runs Dijkstra twice: first to find the shortest path between the nodes and then to find the second shortest path that is edge-disjoint with the first path. In order to maintain this disjointness, it modifies a bit the inital graph, before the second run of Dijkstra (but that's not important here).

What results would that algorithm give for the graph below and nodes $A$ and $D$?

[image]

If I have understood correctly, with Suurballe's algorithm the first run of Dijkstra would give the path $A\to B\to C\to D$ and the second run would give $A\to D$. Then, the final cycle would be $A\to B\to C\to D\to A$ with total cost 18.

But this graph has a shorter cycle: $A\to C\to D\to B\to A$ with total cost 17. Note that this cycle can be obtained by combining paths $A\to B\to D$ and $A\to C\to D$, none of which is a shortest path between $A$ and $D$.

What have I gotten wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first run of Dijkstra has found $A\to B\to C\to D$, the weights of the graph are changed for the second run. I have not checked it, but I guess that in that updated graph, the second run will find path $A\to C\to B\to D$.

These two paths traverse edge $BC$ in opposite directions, so that section is removed. The remaining parts of the paths are reassembled (head of one path with the tail of the other) to get the two paths $A\to C\to D$ and $A\to B\to D$. Together these form the shortest cycle $A\to C\to D\to B\to A$.

The example in the wiki page illustrates the process quite well.

Comment: I checked it and indeed that's what happens. Silly me... :)